# Thunderbird beta does not open link

Tags: thunderbird

I have installed the Thunderbird beta (86.0b1) via the snap package on Ubuntu 20.04. I have used it for some months now without any issues. This morning, however, it suddenly opened with a brand new profile and even though my old one is still there I cannot open links from E-Mails anymore. Instead, it prompts me with an empty "Choose application" screen and if I browse to "/usr/bin/firefox" and select firefox, nothing happens.
The same pop-up is shown when I try to change the http handler within the settings.

Comment: Questions on beta products are not something Ask Ubuntu handles. That is for the developer of Thunderbird.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the heads up!

Comment: I have the same problem.  Don't know how I got on the beta release channel in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to downgrade Thunderbid:

```
sudo snap refresh thunderbird --channel=stable
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't open my profile after the downgrade because changes have been made by a newer version than the stable one.